# A graph and its complement both have diameter 3

Tags: graph-theory

Let G be a graph. When is it true that G and G complement both have diameter 3?

Example: P_4 the path on 4 vertices. It's self-complementary. Since it has diameter 3, both it and its complement have diameter 3.

Besides P_4, what graphs have this property?

Answer (score 2):

Lots and lots of them.

Start with any graph $G$ and add four vertices $\{a,b,c,d\}$ such that $ab, bc, cd$ are edges and, additionally, $b$ and $c$ are adjacent to every vertex of $G$.

No matter what $G$ looks like, the result has diameter $3$: you can't get from $a$ to $d$ in fewer than three steps. But you can get from any vertex of $G$ to any other in two steps (by going through $b$ or $c$), from $a$ or $d$ to any vertex of $G$ in two steps (in the same way) and from $b$ or $c$ to any vertex of $G$ in one step.

The complement of this graph also has diameter $3$. In fact, the complement has the same structure: $a$ and $d$ have edges to every vertex in the complement of $G$ (and to each other) while $b$ and $c$ have edges only to $d$ and $a$ respectively. It takes three steps to get from $b$ to $c$, and any other pair of vertices are at most two steps apart.

Essentially, we can take $P_4$ and an arbitrary graph, connect them in the right way, and preserve the property that $P_4$ had.

Comment: And of course lots of self-complementary graphs of diameter $3.$

Comment: @bof In fact, iterating the construction in this answer is one way to construct self-complementary graphs of size $4k$ and $4k+1$ for all $k$, if we start with $P_4$ and $C_5$. There's lots of self-complementary graphs, but I don't know of good ways to generate lots of examples, especially if we require the diameter $3$ condition.